# In hexadecimal calculus, the square of a positive integer x is 2 identical blocks each of length k. can k be equal to 2023?

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

In hexadecimal calculus, the square of a positive integer x is 2 identical blocks each of length k. can k be equal to 2023?

I transferred the required number to the decimal number system and got ab ... yzab ... yz (16) = (z * 1 + y * 16 + ... + a16 ^ 2022) * (16 ^ 2023 + 1), (10)I also realized that if the number in the hexadecimal number system is a square, then in the decimal number system it is also a square.

Comment: Of course, a positive integer is either a square or not. It has nothing to do with the particular base you choose to write the number down. You could use Roman numerals, it's still the same number and will either be a square or not. Specifically: the number $x\in\mathbb N$ is a square if and only if there is a number $y\in\mathbb N$ such that $x=y\cdot y$. No specific base referenced.

Comment: In other words.  Can $a(16^{2023} + 1) = m^2;a<16^{2023}$ be possible?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Assuming you don't allow leading zeros, you want a square of the form
$$ x^2 = (16^{2023}+1) b$$
where $16^{2022} \le b < 16^{2023}$.  Now it turns out that $16^{2023} + 1$ is divisible by $17^2$ (this is true because $2023$ is odd and divisible by $17$).  Thus we can take
$$ x = \frac{(16^{2023}+1)\cdot 16}{17}, \ b = \frac{(16^{2023}+1) \cdot 16^2}{17^2} $$

Comment: Sorry, but if b is equal to this, then we will definitely be able to pick up such a, b, ...., y, z equal from 0 to 15, what we get is b?

Comment: My $b$ is a number with $2023$ digits in base $16$, each of them $0$ to $15$. .

Comment: why b is divisible by 17 ^ 2?

Comment: $b$ is not, $16^{2023}+1$ is.  $x^{kp} + 1 = (x^k + 1)(x^{k(p-1)} - x^{k(p-2)} + \ldots - x^k + 1)$.  Take $x = 16$ and $p = 17$, and note that $x \equiv -1 \mod 17$ to see that $16^k + 1$ and $16^{16 k} - 16^{15 k} + \ldots  - 16^k + 1$ are both divisible by $17$.