# Prove that $16 ^ {2023} + 1$ is divisible by $17 ^ 2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, binomial-theorem

> Prove that $16 ^ {2023} + 1$ is divisible by $17 ^ 2$.

It is clear that $16 ^ {2023} + 1$ is divisible by $17$, but why it is divisible by $17 ^ 2$ is not clear.

Comment: Look up a proof to lifting the exponent lemma. Note that 17 is a divisor of 2023.

Comment: @All FYI, note that this question is likely being asked due to the OP's question [In hexadecimal calculus, the square of a positive integer x is 2 identical blocks each of length k. can k be equal to 2023?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127997/in-hexadecimal-calculus-the-square-of-a-positive-integer-x-is-2-identical-block/3128012#3128012)'s answer by Robert Israel uses that $17^2$ divides into $16^{2023}$. His explanation is "this is true because $2023$ is odd and divisible by $17$", with these reasons being generally expanded on in the answers here.

Comment: Please don't change your question. If you have another question, then please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint.

Use $2023=7\cdot17^2$, $16=17-1$  and the binomial of Newton.

Now we see that $16^{2023}+1$ is divisible even by $17^3$.